# Как перезаписывать календарь jqueryui datepicker по клику?

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

Есть календарь, слева период, при нажатии на который надо подсветить выбранный период от текущей даты.
У меня возникла идея при клике на нужный период перезаписывать datepicker, но я не придумаю как это сделать.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Слух, что если полноценно юзать через `datetimepicker`?